# How should I transform "Jane has just broken her leg" into a question starting with "Who" and whose answer is "Jane"?

Tags: word-choice, questions, singular-they, possessive-determiners, generic-they

How should I transform this sentence into a question?

> Jane has just broken her leg.

How do I form a question from that sentence so that it starts with *who* and whose answer is *Jane*?

> Q: Who__________?
>
> A: Jane.

Is it all right to ask it this way:

> Who has just broken **his or her** leg?

Comment: Why not "Has Jane broken her leg?" Don

Comment: Because Jane has to be an answer